# 404 Jersery web.xml not working

Tags: java, xml, rest, maven, jersey

I can't make Jersey to work with glassfish. I don't understand what does not work. I'm pretty desesperate right now:

[image: Server & App running]

I get 404 when I try to access to one of the following URLs:

- http://localhost:8080/api
- http://localhost:8080/rest/api
- http://localhost:8080/UPMSocial_130171_130074/api
- http://localhost:8080/UPMSocial_130171_130074/rest/api

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>UPMSocial_130171_130074</groupId>
  <artifactId>UPMSocial_130171_130074</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- if you are using Jersey client specific features without the server side -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
 <display-name>UPMSocial_130171_130074</display-name>
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>upm.social.servicios.Servidor</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Servidor.java

```
@Path("/api")
public class Servidor {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Response getUsers(
```

Comment: Only those url's in particular? Does every other url work as expected? And, do you have any type of error log you can provide?

Comment: No URL work and the log seems ok with no errors. WEB-INF/lib is empty because `<scope>provided</scope>` thats probably my problem.

Comment: Since glassfish already have Jersey it seems it have to be configured as provided.

Comment: Usually, if you don't have a context root defined, it gets the name of your WAR which would be `UPMSocial_130171_130074-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`. If that's the case, then you should access your REST API the following way: *http://localhost:8080/UPMSocial_130171_130074-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/rest/api*.

Comment: @aribeiro I also have tried that with no luck.

Comment: @JesúsMartínBerlanga, do you require a *web.xml*? If not, you could use the *ApplicationPath* approach.

Comment: @aribeiro I thought web.xml was a more standart way, and thus a better approach.

Comment: Using a class that extends Application and annotate it with `@ApplicationPath` is way simpler. Take a look at the following links: [REST example with Application](http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/rest-example-with-application/README.html), [Packaging with an Application subclass](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24983/configure.htm#RESTF182) and [Jersey Application with no web.xml](http://www.connect2java.com/webservices/jax-rs-applicationpath-annotationno-web-xml-example-in-jersey/).

Comment: I don't know what was the problem but I simplified the Servidor code and changed param-value to point to the package and it's working now